# How to measure resources are consumptioned by thread in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to track the currently running thread execution to measure the it's performance like **Memory usage**,**CPU usage** and **Global cache misses** etc...
I have able to measured the CUP usage consumed by the running thread using `java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean`

**Get CPU time for the thread**

```
ThreadMXBean tmxb = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
long cpuTime = tmxb.getThreadCpuTime(aThreadID);
```

But i couldn't get the other values.So my question is that,is there any API available to measure the Thread performance or how to get it by using native way.

Comment: Each thread has its own stack, which has a fixed size. For the rest, the whole principle of threads is that they all share the same memory, so asking for the memory usage of a thread doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

There's usually a jconsole executable in the bin folder of the jdk. Execute it, connect your process and it will list all the managed beans.

The java.lang folder is the one you're looking for.